# Need help choosing a survey question

Tags: estimation, experiment-design, inference

How should I phrase a question to ask people about problems they experience?

My organization has a population of ~250 scientists, all working in the same general area. We are seeing schedule slippage (the problem) in many projects and believe there are some common causes. We have inferred that we have four types of schedule slip causes: A, B, C, and D.

We want to know, on a weekly or bi-weekly basis, the types and number of problems the scientist experience in order to prioritize initiatives to eliminate causes. We plan to survey a sample of the population. The first few surveys will establish a baseline to which we can compare efficacy of the initiatives.

1) Would this question objectively gather data, would another phrasing work better?

"Please enter the number of times you've experienced problems
    of these types: [   ] A. [   ] C. [   ] D. [   ] E.

2) Can I presume population is "normal" in order to calculate sample size?

3) From the sample responses, how do I calculate the statistic for the frequency of problems from each of the four types for the population.

Thanks for any pointers.